# Is there a way to put in a buffer FBO texture output format GL_ALPHA?

Tags: c++, opengl, alphablending, fbo, ftgl

I am using ftgl font library.

ftgl function to create image has this code:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, textureWidth, textureHeight,0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureMemory);
```

Format GL_ALPHA.

When I render to FBO images(GL_RGBA) they look ok.
But when I render fonts to fbo texture, there is some problems with colour and alpha.

This image should open in editor that don't touch pixels(browser uses anti-aliasing).

[image]

---

Code:

/// 1 step create FBO

```
 // Create the color buffer
    glGenTextures(1, &id_tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id_tex);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, wid, hei, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL); // GL_RGBA GL_ALPHA

    // Create the frame buffer
    glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &id_buf);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, id_buf);
    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, id_tex, 0);

    GLenum err = glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT);
    assert(err == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_EXT);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

/// 2 step render to fbo

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);    
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, id_buf);       
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glClearColor (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glViewport(0,0, 1920 , 1080);
```

ftgl::render();

```
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);                    
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glFlush ();     
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);

glViewport (0, 0, 1920, 1080);
glClearColor (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

/// 3 step render texture

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id_tex);
glBegin(GL_QUADS); 

glTexCoord2d(0,0); glVertex3f(point4.X , point4.Y , point4.Z);
glTexCoord2d(0,1); glVertex3f(point1.X , point1.Y , point1.Z);
glTexCoord2d(1,1); glVertex3f(point2.X , point2.Y , point2.Z);
glTexCoord2d(1,0); glVertex3f(point3.X , point3.Y , point3.Z);

glEnd();
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. You say that "there is some problems with colour and alpha". OK: what are the problems?

Comment: I am not sure if GL_ALPHA is an accepted internal format at all.

Comment: Pixels with transparent deleted or different when i rendering texture from fbo. 
In image it can be seen.